# Grouping method

Tags: mysql, grouping

I am working on a query with the following format:
I require all the columns from the Database 'A', while I only require the summed amount (sum(amount)) from the Database 'B'.

```
    SELECT A.*, sum(B.CURTRXAM) as 'Current Transaction Amt'
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN C
    ON A.Schedule_Number  = C.Schedule_Number
    LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.DOCNUMBR = B.DOCNUMBR
    ON A.CUSTNMBR = B.CUSTNMBR

    GROUP BY A
    ORDER BY A.CUSTNMBR
```

My question is regarding the grouping statement, database A has about 12 columns and to group by each individually is tedious, is there a cleaner way to do this such as:

```
    GROUP BY A
```

I am not sure if a simpler way exists as I am new to SQL, I have previously investigated GROUPING_ID statements but thats about it.

Any help on lumped methods of grouping would be helpful

Comment: I guess that grouping by all columns from A is actually _not_ what you need. What you try to do here is, I believe, to `SELECT` all columns from A with corresponding values, and append a `SUM`. Is that right? And if so, is A.DOCNUMBER a unique key or not?

Comment: Yes, the docunumber uniquely identifies the values I want. I actually ran my query without the summation term and it works. I just have to manually sum the results on excel (due to a results deadline I had to meet). I also grouped it by simply just asking for the accountnumber in the select but this is not what the end user wants.

Comment: 1. What is `RM20401`? 2. The `ORDER BY` clause comes after the `GROUP BY` clause. 3. LEFT JOIN C is likely to lead to adding `CURTRXAM` values multifold. Is this desired?

Comment: Hi Thomas, 1)A typo, RM20401 should be 'A'  2)another typo when transferring my sql query to stackoverflow 3)No C is basically just a header table for B, its basically used for the where clause statements (I am not sure if this answers your question)

Answer (score 0):

Since the docnumber is the primary key - just use the following SQL:

```
SELECT A.*, sum(B.CURTRXAM) as 'Current Transaction Amt'
FROM A
LEFT JOIN C
ON A.Schedule_Number  = C.Schedule_Number
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.DOCNUMBR = B.DOCNUMBR
ORDER BY RM20401.CUSTNMBR 
GROUP BY A.DOCNUMBR
```